Is $\sum_{\substack{n_1+\ldots+n_k=2m\\ n_1,\ldots,n_k\in\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}}}x_1^{n_1}\cdots x_k^{n_k} \geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^k$?
Is the sum of all monomials of the same even total degree positive ?.
In other words:
$$
\mbox{Is}\ \sum_{\substack{n_1\ +\ \cdots\ +\ n_k\ =\ 2m\\[1mm] n_1,\ldots,n_k\ \in\ \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}}}x_1^{n_1}\ldots x_k^{n_k} \geq 0\qquad\forall\ x\in\mathbb R^k\quad\mbox{and}\quad \forall\ m,k\in\mathbb N\ ?
$$
Motivation:

I want to understand the sign behavior of the divided differences of $x\mapsto x^{-2m-1}$, and I found that these are a constant times $x_1^{-1}\cdots x_k^{-1}$ times the above sum with $x$ substituted for $x^{-1}$.
I tried aranging $|x_1|\geq|x_2|\cdots\geq|x_k|$ without loss of generality and comparing the positive and negative terms, but to no avail.
I also don't know the answer for $m=1$.


For $m = 1$ you have $\sum_i x_i^2 + \sum_{{i,j\ne i}} x_i x_j = \frac12 [(\sum_i x_i)^2 + \sum_i x_i^2 ] \ge 0 $ so that's fine...

Good point, thanks! Do you think that would work for m>1 as well?

Sorry for bits and pieces. For $k=2$ you have $x_1^{2m} \sum_{k=0}^{2m} (x_2/x_1)^k = \frac{x_1^{2m +1 }- x_2^{2m +1 }}{x_1 - x_2} > 0 $ so that's also fine.

If one could show that $f$ is convex then $0 = f(0) = f\left( \frac{x + (-x)}{2}\right) \le \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2} = f(x) $. I had claimed that in a (now deleted) answer, but the proof was wrong.

Great point, I added convex-analysis as a tag.

@Andreas In fact, this identity is (in some sense) crucial. The proof I posted below is just a generaliztion of this idea.

Is there no simpler proof?

Here is a proof of your conjecture: Schur convexity and positive definiteness of the even degree complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials

Hahaha nice! Including strict positivity for $x\neq0$.

I think this link and references therein might be useful as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur-convex_function

Yes, this is true. (I encountered this problem some time ago but could not remember the source.)
We will need several relatively well-known facts (proofs of some of them are only sketched here).

Lemma 1 (Lagrange interpolation). For any distinct $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $y_1,\ldots,y_k\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists a unique polynomial $f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ of degree at most $k-1$ such that $f(x_i)=y_i$. Moreover, this polynomial is given by the following formula:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}y_i\cdot\prod_{j\neq i}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}.
$$

Proof. Indeed, it is clear that the polynomial on the left hand side takes value $y_i$ at $x=x_i$. On the other hand, such a polynomial is unique since a non-zero polynomial of degree at most $k-1$ cannot vanish at $k$ distinct points. $\square$

Lemma 2 (A formula for $h_r$). Denote by $h_r$ the so-called complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial of degree $r$ in $k$ variables $x_1,\ldots,x_k$, i.e.
$$
h_r(x_1,\ldots,x_k)=\sum_{\substack{i_1+\ldots+i_k=r\\i_1,\ldots,i_k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}}x_1^{i_1}\ldots x_k^{i_k}.
$$
Then, the following identity holds:
$$
h_r(x_1,\ldots,x_k)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{x_i^{r+k-1}}{\prod_{j\neq i}(x_i-x_j)}.
$$

Proof. This is a classical fact from the theory of symmetric functions (see the book by Macdonald, for instance). One way to prove the assertion of the lemma is by induction on $r$ or $k$. Alternatively, one can prove identities for all $r$ simultaneously by using the generating functions: note that $\sum_{r\ge 0} h_r(x_1,\ldots,x_k)z^r=\prod_{i=1}^{k}(1-zx_i)^{-1}$ if we set $h_0\equiv 1$. See also here. $\square$

Lemma 3 (A generalization of MVT). Let $F\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $k-1$ times differentiable function. Then, for any $k$ distinct points $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ on $[a,b]$ there exists $\xi\in (a,b)$ such that the following identity holds:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{F(x_i)}{\prod_{j\neq i}(x_j-x_i)}=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}F^{(k-1)}(\xi).
$$

Remark. For $k=1$ the statement is trivial while for $k=2$ this is just the mean value theorem.
Proof. Firstly, we reduce the statement to the case when $F(x_1)=\ldots=F(x_k)=0$. Indeed, denote $y_i=F(x_i)$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and use Lemma 1 to obtain a polynomial $g$ with $\deg g\leq k-1$ such that $g(x_i)=y_i$ for all $i$. From the formula in Lemma 1 it also follows that the $x^{k-1}$ term of $g$ equals
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{y_i}{\prod_{j\neq i}(x_i-x_j)}=
\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{F(x_i)}{\prod_{j\neq i}(x_i-x_j)}.
$$
In particular, for any $\xi\in(a,b)$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{(k-1)!}g^{(k-1)}(\xi)=
\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{F(x_i)}{\prod_{j\neq i}(x_j-x_i)}.
$$
Now, if we denote $G(x)=F(x)-g(x)$ for $x\in[a,b]$, then our problem reduces to the following: assuming that distinct $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in[a,b]$ are such that $G(x_1)=\ldots=G(x_k)=0$, show that there exists $\xi\in(a,b)$ satisfying $G^{(k-1)}(\xi)=0$. This follows from Rolle's theorem applied $k-1$ times. $\square$
Proof of the inequality.
Finally, we are ready to prove the the original inequality. In our notation, this is equivalent to $h_{2m}(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\geq 0$ for any real numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_k$. Using the continuity, we may assume without loss of generality that all $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ are distinct. Then, by Lemma 2 and Lemma 3 applied to $F(x)=x^{2m+k-1}$ for $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ there exists $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
h_{2m}(x_1,\ldots,x_k)=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}F^{(k-1)}(\xi)=\binom{2m+k-1}{k-1}\cdot \xi^{2m}.
$$
Since $\xi^{2m}$ is non-negative, the inequality $h_{2m}(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\geq 0$ follows.
Remark. I believe (but not sure) that the equality holds only when $x_1=\ldots=x_k=0$, but the argument (in the current form) cannot be applied for proving this. However, one may try to modify Lemma 3 (for polynomial $F$, say) to fix this issue.
An update. As @Martin wrote in the comments, the equality indeed holds only for all $x_i=0$. See here for the proof and general context about Schur-convexity.

I re-read the original post again and realized that the author is most likely aware about Lemma 2 -- it is just another formula for iterated divided differences (as well as the Lagrange formula in some sense).

Superb, thank you so much! Did you encounter the problem in the context of divided differences as well?

@Teun No, I looked at this problem some years ago during high school or undergraduate studies (it was a really difficult problem). The original problem statement was the same as in your post -- only after some time I realized the connection to divided differences. By the way, note that Lemma 3 is quite useful for getting (at least) some information for the iterated divided difference of a sufficiently smooth function.


That the form of degree $2m$ is positive definite is stated explicitly by Jakob Grommer, Ganze transzendente Funktionen mit lauter reellen Nullstellen, 1914, p130-131 (Problem 51, Pólya-Szegő, vol II)

Whiteley J. N. (1958 & 1961) appears to have shown the convexity. See  Beckenbach & Bellman - Inequalities, I & 35 where the following  formula appears:


$$\int_{[0,\infty)^k} (\sum_{i=1}^k a_i x_i)^N e^{-(a_1 + \cdots + a_k)} d a_1 \cdots d a_k = N! S_N(x_1, \ldots x_k)$$
from where the positivity and convexity follows if $N$ even.

The convexity is in some recent papers attributed to Hunter.  What Hunter did is finding the minimal value of $S_{2n}$ on a  sphere. If $k$ is even it appears that the minimal value is achieved when half of the values equal the negative of the other half. Hunter stated this as a conjecture, and also proved a weaker limiting inequality.

$\bf{Added:}$ an example of the integral formula
From the integral formula we get
$$ (s_n(x))^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
is subadditive (so convex) in $x$ (use Minkowski integral inequality)
$$(n! s_n(x))^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ increasing in $n$
(use Jensen inequality)
( $n$ even or $x\ge 0$), these are just some conclusions. One could tackle some other symmetric functions.

In the formula in (2) should it be rather $(\sum_{i}a_ix_i)^N$ in the integral? Otherwise, the LHS would be just a multiple of the $N$-th power sum in $x_i$'s.

@richrow: Yes indeed, thank you!
